# How to check if checked checkboxes are in a consecutive order using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I am creating a form

- I would like to check if the checkboxes that are checked,
- if the checked elemens are in a consecutive order.

Examples:

- Check if 3 or more checkboxes are checked, and also if they are in a consecutive order for example if 1-2-3 checkboxes are checked.
  Once this is verified then the data-calculate price to be `84.10`.
- If 1-2-5 checkboxes are checked then the data-calculate attribute for all checkboxes to be `99.00`.
- If 3-4-5-6-7 checkboxes are checked then the data-calculate to be `79.10`.

I will provide the HTML and JS code for you to understand. The code is working but I want to add the consecutive weeks also. I added a comment about where my the extra code should go. Here is my code. If something is not clear please let me know to make it clear. Thanks.

HTML Code

```js
const week1 = document.querySelector(".c_week_1");
const week2 = document.querySelector(".c_week_2");
const week3 = document.querySelector(".c_week_3");
const week4 = document.querySelector(".c_week_4");
const week5 = document.querySelector(".c_week_5");
const week6 = document.querySelector(".c_week_6");
const week7 = document.querySelector(".c_week_7");

let allCheckboxes = [week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7];

let hatCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hat-checkbox")
let tshirtCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-tshirt-checkbox")
let usbCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-usb-checkbox")


let tshirtPrice = 0;
let hatPrice = 0;
let usbPrice = 0;
let tripsPrice = 0;

let count = 0;

allCheckboxes.forEach((box, index) => {



  box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    let sum = 0;

    if (box.checked) {
      count++
    } else {
      count--
      box.dataset.calculate = 99.00;
    }

    sum = count * 28.5;


    allCheckboxes.forEach(box => {

      if (box.checked) {

        if (count > 5 && count <= 7) {

          // Here is the 3-7 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          // Here is the 3-7 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          // Here is the 3-7 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          box.dataset.calculate = 79.20;

        } else if (count >= 3 && count <= 5) {

          // Here is the 3-4 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          // Here is the 3-4 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          // Here is the 3-4 weeks consecutive checkboxes checked
          if (box[index - 1] === box[index] - 1 && box[index + 1] ===
            box[index] + 1) {

            _log("working");

          } else {

            _log("not working")

          }

          box.dataset.calculate = 84.15;

        } else {
          // Normal price without discount
          box.dataset.calculate = 99.00;

        }

        sum = sum + parseFloat(box.dataset.calculate);

      }

    });

    let tshirtResult = tshirtCheckboxes.forEach((box) => {
      box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        tshirtPrice = parseFloat(e.target.dataset.calculate)
        document.querySelector('.c_final_price_1_kid').innerText = parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4)) + tshirtPrice + hatPrice + usbPrice;
      })
    })

    let hatResult = hatCheckboxes.forEach((box) => {
      box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        hatPrice = parseFloat(e.target.dataset.calculate)
        document.querySelector('.c_final_price_1_kid').innerText = parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4)) + tshirtPrice + hatPrice + usbPrice;
      })
    })

    let usnResult = usbCheckboxes.forEach((box) => {
      box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        usbPrice = parseFloat(e.target.dataset.calculate)
        document.querySelector('.c_final_price_1_kid').innerText = parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4)) + tshirtPrice + hatPrice + usbPrice;
      })
    })

    let result = document.querySelector('.c_final_price_1_kid').innerText = parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4));

  })
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_1" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>2</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_2" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>3</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_3" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>4</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_4" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>5</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_5" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>6</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_6" data-calculate="99">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>7</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c_week_7" data-calculate="99">
  </div>

  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <span>TSHIRT</span>
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
    </div>
    <span>Hat</span>
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
  </div>
  <div class="c-checkbox-box">
    <span>USB</span>
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
  </div>

</form>

<div class="c_final_price_1_kid"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the consecutive weeks"?

Comment: I would like to get all the checkboxes that are checked and check if they are in a consecutive order. I have 7 checkboxes and each checkbox represent 1 week if its checked. I would like to know how many checkboxes are checked in order to see what weeks are chosen. If they choose 1-2-3 weeks they are consecutive weeks and I would like to add a discount by changing the data-calculate  attribute to become 84.15. If they choose 1-3-6 they are not in a consecutive order(weeks) and I would like my data-calculate to be 99.00. if there are 5 or more make the data-calculate value to be 79.20

Comment: How are you calculating the discount based on the consecutiveness? Is there an algorithm?

Comment: Check the code. I added a comment where it says consecutive weeks. There is where I want my code to go. The rest code is working properly. I just want to add the extra code for the consecutive weeks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your event listener:

```js
let checkedBoxes = allCheckboxes.filter(box => box.checked).map(v => v.class.charAt(v.length-1)).sort();
let newPrice = 100;
checkedBoxes.forEach((v, i) => {
  if (checkedBoxes.length > 5 && checkedBoxes[i+2]-2 === v && v == checkedBoxes[i+1]-1 === v && v == checkedBoxes[i+3]-3 === v && v == checkedBoxes[i+4]-4 === v && v == checkedBoxes[i+5]-5 === v && newPrice > 79.2)
    newPrice = 79.2;
  else if (checkedBoxes.length > 2 && checkedBoxes[i+2]-2 === v && v == checkedBoxes[i+1]-1 === v && newPrice > 84.15)
    newPrice = 84.15;
  else if (newPrice > 99)
    newPrice = 99.00;
});
box.dataset.calculate = newPrice;
```

Comment: There is an error in the code @Rojo

Comment: @NoName84 What's the error?

Comment: maybe im adding the code somewhere else. Can you please be for specific of where to add the code and what to delete?

Comment: @NoName84 Replace your `.forEach` function with mine

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 percent sure on your desire here but I took this as maximum number of   items in a sequence with no gaps for the `maxSeq` calculation.

I did some class additions and simplified code so functions only do one thing as needed.  I created some global objects (debatable practice) to hold the values but you can namespace those or otherwise improve that.

Rather than do a complicated calculation sequence I simply did the counts then dispatched events to set prices.(assumptions made on that based only on what I saw).

This is a super fast example and not 100% production ready.

```js
const allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.weeks-container .c-checkbox-box  input[type="checkbox"].c-week');
const hatCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hat-checkbox");
const tshirtCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-tshirt-checkbox");
const usbCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".c-usb-checkbox");
// console.log(allCheckboxes.length);

let prices = {
  tshirtPrice: 0,
  hatPrice: 0,
  usbPrice: 0,
  tripsPrice: 0,
  currentValue: 0
};
let baseValues = {
  low: 28.50,
  mid: 79.20,
  hi: 84.15,
  max: 99.00
};
let calcItems = {
  checkedCount: 0,
  seqCount: 0
};

function checkSequenceCount(checks) {
  let maxCount = 0;
  let count = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < (checks.length - 1); i++) {
    if (checks[i].index == (checks[i + 1].index - 1)) {
      count++;
      let resetMax = maxCount <= count;
      maxCount = resetMax ? count : maxCount;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  return maxCount;
}

function getCheckedList(checks) {
  const checkedChecks = [];
  checks.forEach(function(check, index, array) {
    if (check.checked)
      checkedChecks.push({
        checked: check.checked,
        index: index
      });
  });
  return checkedChecks;
}

function handleRadioChange(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
}

function handleChange(event) {
  let box = this;
  const checkedList = getCheckedList([...allCheckboxes]);
  //  console.log("list:", checkedList);
  const checked = [...allCheckboxes].filter(cbx => cbx.checked);
  let numberChecked = checked.length;
  let maxSeq = checkSequenceCount(checkedList);
  calcItems.seqCount = maxSeq;
  calcItems.checkedCount = numberChecked;
  if (maxSeq > 5) {
    baseValues.currentValue = baseValues.mid;
  }
  if (maxSeq == 3 || maxSeq == 4) {
    baseValues.currentValue = baseValues.hi;
  } else {
    // Normal price without discount
    baseValues.currentValue = baseValues.max;
  }
  const hatSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="c-equipement1"]:checked');
  const usbSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="c-equipement3"]:checked');
  const shirtSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="c-equipement"]:checked');
  if (!!hatSelected) {
    hatSelected.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
  }
  if (!!usbSelected) {
    usbSelected.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
  }
  if (!!shirtSelected) {
    shirtSelected.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
  }

  // this doesn't run after 0 seconds but makes it run after the dispatched events
  setTimeout((element) => {
    element.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
  }, 0, box);

}

function allCalc(event) {
  // console.log('C:', calcItems, prices);
  const sum = baseValues.currentValue * calcItems.checkedCount;
  const priceAll = (parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4)) + prices.tshirtPrice + prices.hatPrice + prices.usbPrice);
  // console.log('All:', priceAll);
  //console.log(prices);
  document.querySelector('.c_final_price_1_kid').innerText = (parseFloat(sum.toFixed(4)) + prices.tshirtPrice + prices.hatPrice + prices.usbPrice);
}

function calculatePrice(event) {
  // console.log("Calc:", this.classList[0]);
  let calcV = parseFloat(event.target.dataset.calculate);

  if (this.classList.contains('shirt')) {
    // console.log("Calc Shirt:", this.classList[0], event.target.dataset.calculate);
    prices.tshirtPrice = calcV;
    //console.log(prices.tshirtPrice);
  }
  if (this.classList.contains('hat')) {
    prices.hatPrice = calcV;
  }
  if (this.classList.contains('usb')) {
    prices.usbPrice = calcV;
  }
  setTimeout((element) => {
    // console.log("Callback 1:do sum");
    element.dispatchEvent(calcEvent);
  }, 0, allCheckboxes[0]);
}

const calcEvent = new Event("calc");

allCheckboxes.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
  elem.addEventListener("calc", allCalc);
});
usbCheckboxes.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("change", handleRadioChange);
  elem.addEventListener("calc", calculatePrice);
});
hatCheckboxes.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("change", handleRadioChange);
  elem.addEventListener("calc", calculatePrice);
});
tshirtCheckboxes.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("change", handleRadioChange);
  elem.addEventListener("calc", calculatePrice);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="weeks-container">
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">4</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">5</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">6</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-checkbox-box">
      <label><span class="week-number">7</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="c-week" data-calculate="99" /></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shirts-container">
    <div class="shirt-checkbox-box">
      <span>TSHIRT</span>
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="shirt c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="shirt c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="shirt c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
      <input type="radio" name="c-equipement2" class="shirt c-tshirt-checkbox" data-calculate="9">
    </div>
    <span>Hat</span>
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="hat c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="hat c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="hat c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement1" class="hat c-hat-checkbox" data-calculate="10">
  </div>
  <div class="equipment-container">
    <span>USB</span>
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="usb c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="0">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="usb c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="usb c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
    <input type="radio" name="c-equipement3" class="usb c-usb-checkbox" data-calculate="17">
  </div>
</form>

<div class="c_final_price_1_kid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However it is not working as expected. It does not get the discount prices

Comment: That whole pricing thing was what I was unclear on the requirements for which was why I based it on  the maximum number of  consecutive indexes in the checkbox (first one) list - not sure what the 1-7 checkboxes are about from a logical standpoint (what to use to multiply then to create whatever price matrix you need)